# Как сохранить HTML строку в JSON

Tags: c#, html, json

как сохранить произвольную строку HTML в Json файл. 
Например

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "html": " style type = \"text/css\" "
}
```

Есть проблемы с экранированием.Как их избежать?

Answer (score 1):

> как сохранить произвольную строку HTML в Json файл

```
#r "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.3\ref\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var o = JObject.Parse("{'id':1}");
o["html"] = JToken.FromObject("<div>\"hello\"</div>");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\json.txt", o.ToString());
```

выводит в файл:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "html": "<div>\"hello\"</div>"
}
```